# Create new categorical column as Cartesian product of two categorical columns

Tags: pandas, categories, interaction

I have two categorical variables in a pandas DataFrame and would like to create a new categorical values whose categories are the Cartesian product of the categories of the other two variables.

The resulting DataFrame would then for instance look as follows:

|  | raw_col_1 | raw_col_2 | combined_var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | X | a -- X |
| 1 | b | X | b -- X |
| 2 | b | Z | b -- Z |
| 3 | a | X | a -- X |

The following code archives this, but I am wondering whether there is a better and less clumpsy way to do so.

```py
# Set up original columns
data = pd.DataFrame({})
data["raw_col_1"] = pd.Categorical(["a", "b", "b", "a"])
data["raw_col_2"] = pd.Categorical(["X", "X", "Z", "X"])

# Create combined variable
data["combined_var"] = np.nan
data["combined_var"] = data["combined_var"].astype("object")
for v_var_1 in data["raw_col_1"].cat.categories:
    for v_var_2 in data["raw_col_2"].cat.categories: 
        data.loc[
            (data["raw_col_1"] == v_var_1) & (data["raw_col_2"] == v_var_2), 
            "combined_var"
        ] = f"{v_var_1} -- {v_var_2}"
```

I also experimented with `.apply(` (see below), but this is much slower.

```
data["combined_var"] = data.dropna(subset=["raw_col_1", "raw_col_2"]).apply(
                    lambda row, col_1="raw_col_1", raw_col_2="raw_col_2": f"{row[col_1]} -- {row[col_2]}",
                    axis=1,
                )
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70117857/6949317) solution works, but is also quite slow compared to my current solution.

Comment: Use `data["combined_var"] = data["raw_col_1"].str.cat(data["raw_col_2"], sep=' -- ')`